# show/hide another combobox, with the help of combobox items

Tags: vb.net

I have a little problem that i'm creating a simple search application which have a TEXT box and some combo boxes and radio buttons and a search button.
radio button names "Videos", "Audios", "Pics" etc..
when radiobutton of video is selected, a combobox is appear having options "YouTube", "Metacafe" etc
I want that when i click "Metecafe" item in combobox of video, an other combo box appear having items Like "Entertainment", "How To", "+18" etc(categories of video search).
so "HOW TO SHOW/HIDE AN OTHER COBOBOX WITH THE HELP OF A COMBOBOX ITEM"
hope you have understood my problem.
[screen shoot](http://goo.gl/FLoJO)
 i don't know it is possible or not becux i'm beginner in VB
my English is not so good so please see below code:)

```
if combobox1.SelectedItem = "PAKISTAN" Then
    combobox2.Visible = True
End if

if combobox1.SelectedItem = "INDIA" Then
    combobox3.visible = true
    combobox2.visible = false
 End if
```

Obviously this code is wrong, this is a example that what i want to do
Thanks to all in advance..

NOTE:
     i have try this codes but its not working..

```
if ComboBox1.Items(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex).ToString() = "PAKISTAN" Then

    ComboBox2.Visible = True

End if
```

sorry for spell and grammatical mistakes:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) Property like this

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "PAKISTAN" Then
        ComboBox2.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Since you are wanting to check for multiple country's you can use a [Select Case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) Statement like this

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        Case "PAKISTAN"
            ComboBox2.Visible = True
            ComboBox3.Visible = False
        Case "INDIA"
            ComboBox3.Visible = True
            ComboBox2.Visible = False
        Case Else
            ComboBox2.Visible = False
            ComboBox3.Visible = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: OMG its solved!! [thanks](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-IDTN-bZpzVI/TicIm_oBlYI/AAAAAAAAGH0/dlTECyJKWrs/s640/thanks.gif)Thank you so much Mark.
Thanks to all peoples for quick response Thanks allot Take Care Have a good Day:-)

Answer (score 1):

Two things are important here:

(a) Which event you're using to /detect/ that the combobox has changed, and
(b) The code you're using to detect what is selected.

I haven't tested this, and I'm coming from a C# / VB6 background, so bear with me if this isn't 100% correct, but I believe using the following should work:

Inside the SelectedIndexChanged event of ComboBox1, insert your code above, EXCEPT.. Change instances like

```
combobox1.SelectedItem = "PAKISTAN"
```

to

```
ComboBox1.Text = "PAKISTAN"
```

The SelectedItem property outputs the selected item object itself, which is a variable type that can't be displayed.. not the /text/ of the currently selected item. There are other ways to access the text associated to that item, but ComboBox1.Text is the easiest. ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() would work also.

Comment: SelectedIndex gives you the Index, SelectedItem gives you the Selected object.

Answer (score 0):

```
If ComboBox1.Items(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex).ToString() = "PAKISTAN" Then

    ComboBox2.Visible = True

End If
```

Comment: Did it compile?  Have you set breakpoints and examined the value of Combobox1.Items(Combobox1.SelectedIndex).ToString()?  Please provide more information for additional assistance.

Comment: i'm creating a simple search application which have a TEXT box and some combo boxes and radio buttons and a search button.
radio button names "Videos", "Audios", "Pics"
when radiobutton of video is selected, a combobox is appear having options "YouTube", "Metacafe" etc
I want that when i click "Metecafe" item in combobox of video, an other combo box appear having items Like "Entertainment", "How To", "+18" etc(categories of video search).
so "HOW TO SHOW/HIDE AN OTHER COBOBOX WITH THE HELP OF A COMBOBOX ITEM"
hope now you have understood my problem.
[screen](http://goo.gl/FLoJO)

Answer (score 0):

Btw is this a web client or window client?

Assuming if you are implementing a web client app and the conditional logic are simple, you may need to trigger a page reload which can be achieve in your markup by specifying an event and set the property for reload to enable. My initial on this from reading your post is that your GUI might not be refreshing or reloading unless it's your intension to not reload the page or refresh the GUI then this should be handle with javascript instead.

I hope I'm interpreting the issue correctly and hopefully this will give you some idea on how to tackle the issue.